# How to emulate Emacs-like registers in Tmux?

Tags: copy-paste, tmux

I've long been using Emacs [registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html) and they are a blessing in many sophisticated editing scenarios (e.g. editing multiple inter-related configuration files, using multiple code snippets, juggling paragraphs and expressions around, etc.). Their versatility is virtually limitless. I've also had a glimpse at Vim [registers](https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/) and for most uses they are largely equivalent. I've encountered some use scenarios when I wished Tmux had a similar feature. The question is: can this be used in Tmux and how to do it?

Comment: @Drew, why delete the `emacs` tag? Emacs provided the context for this feature to me and it's no less relevant to the question than Vim.

Comment: It's not a question about Emacs. It's fine to refer to Emacs in the title and description, but it's not an Emacs question.

Comment: It's not about Vim either. What I mean is that if tags serve as associative metadata, then registers will frequently be associated with Emacs. True, it doesn't make it an Emacs question, but if I were looking for a discussion of such a feature and did not know the terminology, I'd think along the lines of "that thing I know from Emacs".

Comment: Someone else (perhaps you) can remove the `vim` tag, if this isn't a question about Vim either. Search is available for all words, not just tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I said to myself: *I'll just go and have a look at the Tmux source code. I'll learn how it handles copy/paste and replicate the behavior for some number of predefined registers, say 26 for each letter of the Latin alphabet*. So I did that and, to my surprise, discovered that the functionality is already there, though not very well-advertised.

The concept is called `buffers` there and affords a simple interface of `set-buffer`, `delete-buffer` and `paste-buffer`. So I thought I'd create two bindings in my `.tmux.conf` - one to replace a user-selected buffer with the selected text (by doing `delete-buffer` first and then `set-buffer`) and another to paste from a user-selected buffer. This almost did the trick, save for the fact that for some reason `delete-buffer` did not handle non-existent buffers gracefully. My then-idea was to initialize 26 buffers under corresponding letters and be done. Today I've tried my approach without the buffers initialized and it still worked. Perhaps newer versions of Tmux handle this better. Anyway, below I'm pasting the relevant configuration snippet:

```
# Initialize alphabetic registers to avoid the problem with 'delete-buffer'
# This might *not* be necessary in newer versions of Tmux
run "tmux set-buffer -b a \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b b \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b c \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b d \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b e \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b f \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b g \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b h \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b i \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b j \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b k \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b l \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b m \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b n \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b o \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b p \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b q \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b r \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b s \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b t \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b u \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b v \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b w \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b x \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b y \"$(echo ' ')\""
run "tmux set-buffer -b z \"$(echo ' ')\""

# Copy to user-selected register
bind -T copy-mode r command-prompt -1 -p '(register)' 'delete-buffer -b %1 ; send -X copy-pipe "tmux set-buffer -n %1"'

# Paste from user-selected register
bind -T prefix C-] command-prompt -1 -p '(register)' 'paste-buffer -b %1'
```

The way to use this setup is as follows:

- to put text in a register you mark it in `copy-mode`, hit <kbd>r</kbd> and answer the prompt for register name
- to paste hit <kbd>C-b C-]</kbd> and answer the prompt - buffer content will get pasted at point

Comment: You do not need to delete buffers before you set them, set-buffer and load-buffer will replace them if they already exist.